# Crude oil and Uranium.in a fantasy world

Tags: magic, low-fantasy

After watching [this Artifexian video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9qvQspSbWc&t=573s) it got me thinking about what I should do with Crude oil and Uranium in my fantasy world. I figure that my Dwarves will definitely find these resources, but it wasn't until the last 100 years or so that we knew what could be with them. I could be wrong about crude oil, but I always heard that we basically did not know what to do with it in the past. This seems wrong now that I am writing this, but I don't know how people in the medieval time period used oil.

What can be done with unrefined oil and uranium? My first thought was to make oil poisonous black sludge, and uranium the green glowing rock that kills. But that seems to be a lazy way out, but less lazy than not dealing with them at all.

I should also keep in mind that my world has magic which will negate some technological need for these things as we use them. Though I have yet to build in the limits of my magic system.

Note for a mod why is "High-Fantasy" not a tag?

Comment: That uranium glows green is true only in the Simpsons. That apart, we don't really work with questions which are basically fishing for ideas, which is what you are doing here.

Comment: Wiki uranium, read applications and history. Minimal research at least please. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#:~:text=Uranium%20is%20a%20chemical%20element,which%206%20are%20valence%20electrons.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica that myth comes from the fact that the most common form of uranium glass (which was a common use for uranium) does glow green under a black light.

Comment: Uranium used to be used in pottery glazes.

Comment: Look up naphtha. and etymology of the word,  petrochemicals have been used for a very long time. Just no where near the modern scale of use.

Comment: Uranium wouldn't be very dangerous if it came with a green warning light!

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica So I am 100% new to this site, as I just found it this week and thought I would ask. I don't quite understand how this stack exchange could possibly not be used to fish for ideas... Definitely not going to revise the question. Like if I had any idea of how these resources could be used in a fantasy would I wouldn't have asked...

Comment: Our [help] gives some explanation on what is a good fit here and what not

Answer (score 1):

Crude oil is used in fuel and a lot of chemicals, though you could also refine it and use it as plastic. As for uranium, I couldn't find any uses for it other than nuclear power, but depleted uranium, which is much less radioactive than natural uranium, is used for ballast and counterweights, as well as armor and ammunition, which might be the best option for a race of dwarves.

Another option would be to change how crude oil/uranium is represented in your world. For example, crude oil could be in a solid form due to the conditions around it, and it could have its own uses, or it could be in the form of poisonous gas veins which pose a threat to the dwarves in the mines.

You could also just take them out completely, as it would be entirely feasible that those two substances either don't exist in the universe/plane/etc or just where the dwarves live.

Comment: The usual advice is to not answer poor questions until they are turned into good shape

Comment: I interpreted the question as "what can be done with crude oil and uranium", which I considered to be a reasonable question that isn't just fishing for ideas.

Comment: "What can I do with X?" is the precise definition of "fishing for ideas", because it can be answered with anything. "Can I use X for Y?" instead has a well defined scope.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, but I felt like this was an understandable question because I have had the same type of problem before and I have had difficulty finding information about something.